# Pip showing up an not installed even though I downloaded python?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.10

**running windows 10 and IDLE python 3.10.1**

I was trying to install pygame with pip using the
`pip install pygame`
command but couldn't get it to work. I've been reading loads of articles trying to figure out what to do but I have no idea.
When I opened up command prompt and typed in
`pip --version` 
following [this website](https://realpython.com/what-is-pip/#getting-started-with-pip)
it came up as running pip version 3.9. I deleted all python 3.9 off my computer in case python 3.10 trying to run pip 3.9 was the problem but now it says

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've deleted and redownloaded python twice now but it still won't work.
Does anyone know what to do? thanks

————————

Hi there just so you know, running python -m pip install pip isn’t working and when i type python —version it says that python was not found?

Comment: `python -m pip install pip` should do the trick.

Comment: Also, is the `Scripts` subfolder of wherever you installed Python in your `PATH`?

Comment: Try adding pip to the path and then try the same command. Visit this [page](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/) and read the section **Adding PIP To Windows Environment Variables**

Comment: @MattDMo You can't use `pip` to install `pip` from scratch; you can only *upgrade* `pip` with itself. `pip` is not part of the standard library.

Comment: @chepner I thought it was included with the standard Windows distribution nowadays, so you don't need to download `get-pip.py`?

Comment: @MattDMo Mm, apparently. I knew `venv` could/does install `pip` automatically in a new virtual environment, but I was under the impression it used `ensurepip` in some way to download it. I'm seeing `python3 -m pip` working with both the stock Python 3 and a HomeBrew-installed Python 3 on my Mac.

Comment: @MattDMo When I ran python -m pip install pip it said that python was not found? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by installing python into my path, I'm quite new to this sorry. :)

Comment: When you install Python, there should be an option (it may be under the "Customize" menu) to install Python globally and add it to your `PATH`.  Make sure that option is checked. Also, just for fun, try running `py -m pip install pip`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with "pip" and than i used this method:
Those are the commands listed for you:

1. `sudo apt install python3`
2. `sudo apt install python3-pip`

This worked for me.

Comment: Hi, I tried typing these into idle and command prompt, both gave me an error code. Happy to hear any other ideas. :)